# Share record(s) based on user custom field?

Tags: custom-field, sharing, user

I have a custom field on my user (`customId`) that corresponds with the value in a custom field on my object (`customId` as well). I'd like for a user with the customId of A2 to only see records where customId = A2 as well.

I'm looking in the sharing rules of my custom object, but it doesn't seem like there's a way to get the current user's customId or anything within the criteria.

Is there a better way to go about this or no way to do it?

Comment: Sharing isn't how you share field data; it's how you determine which records get shared.  I think you want a formula that shares a value from a related object.  Is your custom object related to the user object?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Apex Sharing if it has to be user's specific id. For more details refer https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_bulk_sharing_creating_with_apex.htm

Comment: another option (if acceptable) would be to set user as owner of the custom object record, this way and set sharing settings to private. This way you won't need do any apex sharing stuff.

Comment: I thought about that but the users that will be creating the records, I don't want them to have to go through a list of ~500 users to find the one who it should belong to.

Comment: I meant, setting owner field of custom object record programmatically using apex trigger.

Comment: That's also possible. Either one is going to require me to write more apex code which I didn't necessarily want to do :P